# Firefox Addon signing error

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Hi im trying to sign my firefox addon trought jpm sign --api-key xxxxxxxxx --api-secret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --xpi /path/to/file
but still get this error:

```
status: 401
response: 
{
  "detail": "JWT iat (issued at time) is invalid. Make sure your system clock is synchronized with something like TLSdate."
}
```

help please I need to sign it or if the firefox review it will it be signed automatically ?
I know that api key and api secret are good because checked them and reload them again with new ones.

Comment: If the firefox review it, it will be signed automatically

Comment: Thank you now I'm feeling a lot better ;)

Comment: And it will be still signed if I update it when I cannot sign it ?

Comment: Yes, You can update your Firefox extension and you would have no problem

Comment: Check that Windows Time Service is Enable

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows, try temporarily changing your system time zone to (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time.

I ran into this problem while on Windows 10.  I was confused because my clock was already synced.  So I changed my system time zone to (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time and it worked.